# Google Ads API is changing the Membership Lifespan without input

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I use the Google Ads API to upload a user list using the `'OfflineUserDataJobService'` and then I change the membership lifespan to 540 days using `'UserListService'` and `'UserListOperation'`, more of the code is below.

After the initial run on my Google Ads Test Account the user/audience list uploads perfectly fine. Including the correct membership lifespan (540 Days). After about 1-2 Days the Audience List is closed and the membership lifespan reads (1 Day).

Is this happening because it is a test account? Or is there another issue altogether?

Thanks!

Function for changing User list membership lifespan:

```py
def update_user_list_membership_lifespan(client, customer_id, list_id, mem_life_span, status, app_id=None):
    """Creates a User List using the name provided.
    Args:
      client: The Google Ads client instance.
      customer_id: The customer ID for which to add the user list.
      list_name: The name of the user list to search.
      list_type: The type of customer list (based on CustomerMatchUploadKeyType).
      app_id: App ID required only for mobile advertising lists.
    Returns:
      The User List resource name.
    """
    print(f'The user list {list_id} will have mem_life_spn updated.')
    user_list_service = client.get_service('UserListService')
    user_list_operation = client.get_type('UserListOperation')

    # Creates the new user list.
    user_list = user_list_operation.update

    user_list.resource_name = f"customers/{customer_id}/userLists/{list_id}"

    user_list.membership_life_span = mem_life_span

    user_list.membership_status = status

    client.copy_from(
        user_list_operation.update_mask,
        protobuf_helpers.field_mask(None, user_list._pb),
    )

    user_list_response = user_list_service.mutate_user_lists(
        customer_id=customer_id, operations=[user_list_operation]
    )
    user_list_resource_name = user_list_response.results[0].resource_name
    print(
        f'User list with resource name "{user_list_resource_name}" was updated.')
    return user_list_resource_name
```